# Error related to thread function accepting void in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

I am getting an error in Linux which says:

In file included from server.c:7: /usr/include/pthread.h:200:15: note: expected ‘void * ()(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void ()(int )’ 200 | void *(__start_routine) (void *), | ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ –

I know that the thread functions must accept a single void* argument and return a void*. Accepting any other arguments is an error. Returning any other result is an error. I am confused on how to format the code below in order to fix the error.

This is the code which is causing the error:

```
if(pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  func , (void*) &connfd) < 0)
    {
        perror("could not create thread");
       
    }

Here is the definition of func:    

void func(int *sockfd)
{
char buff[MAX];
int n;
// infinite loop for chat
for (;;) {
    bzero(buff, MAX);
    // read the message from client and copy it in buffer
    read(*sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    // print buffer which contains the client contents
    printf("From client: %s\t To client : ", buff);
    bzero(buff, MAX);
    n = 0;
    // copy server message in the buffer
    while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n');
    // and send that buffer to client
    write(*sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    // if msg contains "Exit" then server exit and chat ended.
    if (strncmp("exit", buff, 4) == 0) {
        printf("Server Exit...\n");
        break;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of `func`.

Comment: I put the definition of func in the body of the question @kaylum

Comment: try changing it to `void func(void * vp) {int * sockfd = (int *) vp; [...]}`

Comment: And note that if `connfd` is a local/stack variable, your program will probably not work reliably since `connfd` will likely have been destroyed before the func() call can run in the other thread and read its value.... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555870/does-using-locals-as-arguments-in-pthread-create-work

Comment: 1. The `func` return type needs to be `void *` and the parameter needs to be `void *` as well. 2. The `func` definition or a forward declaration must occur before it is used in `pthread_create`.

Comment: I still get the same error message :         In file included from server.c:7:
/usr/include/pthread.h:200:15: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(pthread_t *)’ {aka ‘void (*)(long unsigned int *)’}
  200 |       void *(*__start_routine) (void *),
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: I changed it to void func(void * vp) {int * sockfd = (int *) vp; [...]} and I still get the same error

Comment: @BetheGirly1, you changed the function parameter's type, but you did not change that function's return type.  The function must return `void *`, not `void`.